# Are those metrics equivalent

Tags: general-topology

> Let $S$ be the set of real sequences which their series absolute convergence
>
> $$S=\left\{a_{n}:\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_{n}|<\infty\right\}$$ And let $$d(a_{n},b_{n})=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_{n}-b_{n}|$$ and $$\rho(a_{n},b_{n})=\sup\{|a_{n}-b_{n}|:n\in \mathbb{N}\}$$
>
> Are those two metrics equivalent?

I am given $a_{n}=(\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}....,0)$ as an counter example, but I can see why

Comment: That's a slightly dangerous re-use of $a_n$. Above, in your question, you have $a_n$ is one real number, and later you have $a_n$ being an element of $S$. Better to use a very different letter, like $V_n=(1/n,1/n,\dots,1/n,0,0,\dots)$ for a sequence of elements in $S$.

Comment: Even your set theory notation for $S$ is slightly confused. It would be better to write: $$S=\{\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}\mid \dots\text{ conditions }\dots\}$$ to be clear that the elements of $S$ are infinite sequences of values.

Answer (score 1):

if $a_n = (\frac{1}{n},...,\frac{1}{n},0,0,0,...)$ (the number of nonzero elements is n) then $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|(a_{n})_{k}| = 1$ but $\sup_k|(a_n)_{k}| = \frac{1}{n}$ hence in the second metric sequence $a_n$ converges to 0.

And as we have one sequence such that it does not converge in $d$ but does converge in $\rho$ the two metrics induce different topologies on the underlying space.

Comment: Another way to see non-equivalence $(S,d)$ is separable (all sequences that start with finitely many rationals and are then all 0's is countable and dense), while $(S,\rho)$ is not (as the elements $\chi_A$ for $A \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ are  uncountable and discrete.